# How to find Win32 API forward reference programmatically?

Tags: winapi

Some Win32 API calls are actually forwarders to other libraries. For example KERNEL32.LeaveCriticalSection is a forward to NTDLL.RtlLeaveCriticalSection. How can I find programmatically that the call of NTDLL.RtlLeaveCriticalSection is actually forward to KERNEL32.LeaveCriticalSection call and vise versa (I'm trying not to use so called system library NTDLL.DLL in my project and to be only use user KERNEL32.DLL)

Comment: I suspect you need to parse the PE executable format are separate forwarding from object records. But: "so called" your say that as if it isn't a system library when it quite clearly is: why do you not want it as a dependency?

Comment: @Richard, I would like to have this without boring parsing of PE :)

Comment: That's tough. It's how it has to be done.

Comment: Just link to kernel32 and omit ntdll.lib from your link line, and you will not link to ntdll. The fact that kernel32 links to ntdll is an implementation detail that does not apply to all versions of Windows. (For example, Windows 95's kernel32 did not link to ntdll.)

Comment: What do you **really** want? I doubt that there is anything useful to be done with the information you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the actual executable file, `kernel32.dll`. Read the PE meta data to find out how the exports are defined.

Attempting to avoid a dependency on `ntdll` is utterly futile. That's because `kernel32` has a hard dependency on `ntdll` and all processes contain `kernel32`. I suspect you are a little confused about what these libraries do, but you are going to have `ntdll` in your process.

Now, you may wish to avoid calling functions from the native API that are exported by `ntdll`. That's quite reasonable, and one of the things that `kernel32` and the other Win32 libraries do is insulate you from the native API. However, Win32 is implemented on top of the native API. It's fine for `kernel32` to use it.

Comment: I am not against that kernel32 uses native API. The main idea is that I do not want there were any native API lower than kernel32 level in my own code.

Comment: There won't be. It's an implementation detail in kernel32 that it delegates that call to ntdll. Denying yourself access to critical sections is hard to rationalise.